# Disable HTTP Methods in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I disable certain HTTP Methods (for example PUT or TRACE) and have Apache send an HTTP "405 Method not allowed".

I've tried the [Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limit) and [LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directives but they seem to send "403 Forbidden".

I have several vhosts - this should be across all of them, in the main httpd.conf.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It really seems that defining the error code is a bit harder than it should be.

However, one workaround MIGHT be using the `mod_rewrite`. Popped that one out of my head due the fact that in at least 99% of impossible-looking Apache problems mod_rewrite can provide its voodoo dance and solve your problem.

If everything else fails, try something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^GET [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST 
RewriteRule .* /yourerrordocuments/405.html [R=405,L]
```

I know that is probably not the nicest solution around, but it *should* kind of work...

Comment: +1 Mod_rewrite voodoo solves all problems (for limited sets of all).

Comment: Mod_rewrite also runs slow regex on every URL process, which slows the server down.  Use with caution.

Comment: Thanks - nice trick setting the response code with R=405. Was hoping there would be a better way so OPTIONS would report the right values but I guess it's not possible

Comment: What version of Apache/mod_rewrite supports the [AND] flag? I only see [OR] (and "and" being implicit): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 4):

For trace method you can add this

```
TraceEnable off
```

in your main configuration file

Answer (score 2):

To enable the rewrite engine, add the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

Please note that by default, rewrite configurations are not inherited across virtual servers. Add RewriteEngine On to each virtual host.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```